# second test being missed in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit

I am totally new to selenium so learning from scratch.

I am creating a test where I want to test each link, verify its has gone to the correct page and then return to the page i started on. The first section is logging into the site and verifying i am on the correct page but I cannot get the second @Test to be executed.

```
@Test
public void LoginTest() {
    driver.navigate().to("https://test.barclays.lifestyleservicesgroup.co.uk/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='security']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='EmailAddress']")).sendKeys("autobarc001@test.lifestylegroup.co.uk");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("Abcd1234!");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-content']/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/span/input")).click();
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-content']/div[2]/h1")).isDisplayed());
}

//Checking claim process link on homepage
@Test
public void claimProcessTest (){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='helpful-info']/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-content']/div[2]/div[1]/h1")).isDisplayed());
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='current-nav']/a")).click();
}

    //Closing browser after execution
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown () {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question relates to your test framework you are using and not WebDriver.  Please rephrase your question and question title to reflect this.

Comment: What is the problem? What did you expect but is not happening?